# Change ordering of loading css files in T3 template

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, css, t3-framework, joomlart

I'm using JoomlaArt template. That template was built on T3 Framework.

They have a integrated way of adding custom CSS file and it is pretty simple. 
Everything what needs to be done is to add `custom.css` file to `/your_template/css` folder.

That file is loaded in `head.php` by following code:

```
<?php 
// CUSTOM CSS
if(is_file(T3_TEMPLATE_PATH . '/css/custom.css')) {
    $this->addStyleSheet(T3_TEMPLATE_URL.'/css/custom.css'); 
}
?>
```

But, problem for me is because that file was first and I need it to be loaded as last css file.

http://prntscr.com/a9fmea

I don't have idea where do I need to do that. Any advice is welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hello Haris and welcome to JSE. The biggest problem you are going to have if you modify any of the template files in order to change the load order is that updating your template in the future will revert your changes. A easy way to accomplish this would be to add a style declaration before the page finishes loading.

1. Save your custom CSS file to the root of your site instead of in the css folder so your template doesn't pick it up automatically.
2. Install [Flexi Custom Code](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/flexi-custom-code) Module from the JED.
3. Set the module position to the debug position for your template and hide the module title
4. Turn off CSS, HTML, and Javascript cleanup
5. enter the code below into the custom code box

---

```
<?php
  $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
  $doc->addStyleSheet(JUri::root() . 'templates/YOUR_TEMLPATE/css/custom.css');
?>
```

That code should put your *custom.css* file in the head section of the site as the last CSS declaration.

Comment: Thanks.

It works. But there must be probably better solution? Where Joomla load modules? If I can find that file where modules are loaded I can simply check which module is last loaded and put this piece of code in that module to load custom.css when it loads that last one module.

EDIT:
Actually it doesn't work. Take a look where it puts it:
http://prntscr.com/a9kbgs

Still it is not last loaded.

Comment: WIthout modifying the core Joomla files I don't believe this to be possible. If you do edit those files they will be overwritten on the next Joomla update. If you are trying to override styles that are being included from another stylesheet later just use the !important declaration on the selectors that are being overwritten.

Answer (score 2):

T3 should be loading the `custom.css` file last.

As a work around, try [EasyScript](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/easyscript) which is free and which [I have used successfully for this purpose](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/15852/120).

An important advantage of using EasyScript or similar over a core hack is that your changes will survive future updates.