# user.css file and bootstrap-rtl.css file

Tags: joomla-3.x, bootstrap

Joomla 3.6.5 default template (protostar), attaches the file 'bootstrap-rtl.css' before the file 'user.css'(the file that user can add their customizes styles there to be override in template.css) by default.

This makes some problems for me, there is only one solution and that is loading user.css before bootstrap-rtl.css. 
How can I force protostar to do this? (I think there are something needed to be changed in 'index.php')

Comment: Why exactly do you want to load the `user.css` before `bootstrap-rtl.css`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably makes most sense for ProtoStar to load `user.css` last but there are a few ways to work around stylesheet load order issues without hacking the core.

**1. jQuery Easy**

[jQuery Easy](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jquery-easy/) can be used to remove the stylesheets and then add them back in the desired order.

**2. Specificity**

Make custom CSS changes specific enough so that they override the other stylesheets regardless of the stylesheet order.

Reference: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/15853/120

**3. Use a Third Party Extension to load your custom CSS file**

Instead of using `user.css` for your custom CSS, try some third party extensions which may load custom CSS files in a different order compared to the ProtoStar `user.css` stylesheet. For example, [EasyScript](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/easyscript/) loads a custom CSS file e.g. `custom.css` last.

Reference: [How can I load the new Protostar custom CSS stylesheet last?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/15852/120)

Comment: Second option is the right way to do it.